# Loop through array of arrays which contain objects and get all specific values from the objects then show to the page JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For each one of the below arrays in the array called data there will be a li (currently there are 3 li's so there are 3 arrays)

I need to loop through the below arrays and from each object get all the 'namespace' values and the 'currentvalue' values.

Then show the first set of 'namespace and currentvalue values' from all the objects in the first array as text in the first li 
and then do the same for third and so on etc... I commented an example of how it should look in the HTML.

Thank you an help!

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
let data = [
        [{_id: "5e9d", namespace: "Effect",  currentvalue: "comet",}, { _id: "1169", namespace: "HazCode",  currentvalue: "50",} , { _id: "1269", namespace: "Duration",  currentvalue: "10s",}],

        [{_id: "6e9d", namespace: "Effect",  currentvalue: "comet/flair",}, { _id: "1119", namespace: "HazCode",  currentvalue: "50",}],

        [{_id: "7e9d", namespace: "Effect",  currentvalue: "flair",},{ _id: "1178", namespace: "HazCode", currentvalue: "29",},]
    ]

    var els = $('.hideMe > li')

    // loop through array
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $.each(data[i], function(index, d){
            els.text(d.namespace + ":" + d.currentvalue + ", ")
        })
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <ul class="hideMe">
     <!-- First Should be <li> Effect: comet, HazCode: 50, Duration: 10s</li>  -->
     <li>lorem</li>
     <!-- Second Should be <li> Effect: comet, HazCode: 29</li>  -->
     <!--   etc...    -->
     <li>lorem</li>
     <li>lorem</li>
  </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can use a `forEach` loop to iterate through each array in `data`. Then you can use `map()` to build the formatted string containing all the `namespace` and `currentvalue` properties which you can add to the relevant `li` using `text()`. Try this:

```
var $els = $('.hideMe > li')
data.forEach((arr, i) => $els.eq(i).text(arr.map(o => `${o.namespace}: ${o.currentvalue}`).join(', ')));
```

```js
let data = [
  [
    { _id: "5e9d", namespace: "Effect", currentvalue: "comet" }, 
    { _id: "1169", namespace: "HazCode", currentvalue: "50" }, 
    { _id: "1269", namespace: "Duration", currentvalue: "10s" }
  ],
  [
    { _id: "6e9d", namespace: "Effect", currentvalue: "comet/flair" }, 
    { _id: "1119", namespace: "HazCode", currentvalue: "50" }
  ],
  [ 
    { _id: "7e9d", namespace: "Effect", currentvalue: "flair" }, 
    { _id: "1178", namespace: "HazCode", currentvalue: "29" }
  ]
]

var $els = $('.hideMe > li')
data.forEach((arr, i) => $els.eq(i).text(arr.map(o => `${o.namespace}: ${o.currentvalue}`).join(', ')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hideMe">
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
</ul>
```

As an aside, be wary of leaving trailing commas in your objects and arrays. Most modern browsers can handle it but some legacy browsers will throw errors because of it. I've removed them all from the example above.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your goal in such a way

```
var els = $('.hideMe > li');
  // loop through array
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let result = '';
    $.each(data[i], function(index, d){
      result += d.namespace + ":" + d.currentvalue + ", ";
    });
    els.eq(i).text(result);
  }
```